# Simple error response in Laravel 5 while JSON request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, asynchronous, response

I have project on Laravel 5, and I need to do async request via jQuery's $.ajax method. 
Laravel can catch exception, and then it render special error template with it's own styles and markup. 
But for async requests this html-code is redundant.
Is there a way to generate error response without laravel's markup on async requests?

Comment: Do you want to change laravel's default black/red error in message or gray/white error message to your custom error messages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you wanted this to write the web service.

To handle this

Goto **app/Exceptions/Handler.php** :

And change this function

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

to

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if ($this->isHttpException($e))
        {
            return $this->renderHttpException($e);
        }
        else
        {
            return parent::render($request, $e);
        }
    }
```

Also if you need to customize in the webview

Change your 404 blade `\resources\views\errors\404.blade.php` here

Comment: That is good. I can use "$request->isXmlHttpRequest()" to override output. Thanks!